# jqplot using a external .js file for the theme?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

It's possible to have a external .js file with the theme configs for jqplot, instead of everytime i put a graph on a page have to put all the theme params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$.getScript("path/to/external.js");
```